# Getting an image from a JSON array

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to parse the first logo image (assets/images/resized/0002/3133/23133v9-max-150x150.png) from this JSON file.

http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/airbnb.js

This is how I parse the other data, but I can't figure out how to get that image:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/airbnb.js",
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(results){
    var number_of_employees = results.number_of_employees;
    var founded_month = results.founded_month;
    var founded_year = results.founded_year;
    $('#number_of_employees').append(number_of_employees);
    $('#founded').append(founded_month + '/' + founded_year);

}
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/airbnb.js",
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(results){
   // ...
   var imgUrl = 'http://crunchbase.com/' + results.image.available_sizes[0][1];
    // Display the image (requires <img id="myImage"/> in the document)
   $('#myImage').attr('src', imgUrl);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Accesspattern for the smallest image: `image.available_sizes[0][1];`.